# Scan Credit Card In Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to scan a credit card on click of an icon in the text field

```
@Composable
fun CardNumber(){

 if(focus){
     IconButton(onClick = {
          context.startActivity(Intent(context, Camera_Preview::class.java))
          Toast.makeText(context, "Camera Initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}){

 Icon(
      painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_camera),
      contentDescription = null,
      tint = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.White else Color.Black
                         )

}
}

}
```

The Icon Button Initializes a camera preview which closes after 5seconds during this period I want to scan card details and return the result to the text field CardNumber and display.

```
@Composable
fun Cameras(){
...
    AndroidView(factory = {previewView}, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build().also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
            }
            val  cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
            } catch (exc: Exception){
                Log.e("EXC", "Camera ${exc.localizedMessage}")
                Toast.makeText(context, "Camera ${exc.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        delay(5000)
        val scanIntent =  Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        context.startActivity(scanIntent)
        scanIntent
    }
}
```

I have tried using card.io it didn't scan the card.

I need help dependencies and implementation of it to scan the card with the camera preview and add the result in the textfield.